# Unknown block type "youtube". Problem with serialization React Portable Text

Tags: reactjs, typescript, serialization, sanity

I added custom block YouTube block using [this tutorial](https://www.sanity.io/guides/portable-text-how-to-add-a-custom-youtube-embed-block). I have problem with render the YouTube embed in a frontend.
[slug].tsx file:

```js
import { GetStaticProps } from 'next';
import Header from '../../components/Header';
import { sanityClient, urlFor } from '../../sanity';
import { Post } from '../../typings';
import PortableText from "react-portable-text";
import YouTube from "react-youtube";
import getYouTubeID from "get-youtube-id";

interface Props {
    post: Post;
}

const serializers = {
    block: ({node}: any) => {
        if (node._type === 'youtube') {
            console.log(`NODE: ${JSON.stringify(node)}`)
            const {url} = node
            const id = getYouTubeID(url)
            return (<YouTube videoId={id}/>)
        }
    },
    normal: (props: any) => (
        <p className=""> {props.children}</p>
    ),
    h1: (props: any) => (
        <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold my-5"> {props.children}</h1>
    ),
    h2: (props: any) => (
        <h2 className="text-xl font-bold my-5"> {props.children}</h2>
    ),

    h3: (props: any) => (
        <h3 className="text-xl font-bold my-5"> {props.children}</h3>
    ),
    h4: (props: any) => (
        <h4 className="text-lg font-bold my-5"> {props.children}</h4>
    ),
    h5: (props: any) => (
        <h5 className="text-base font-bold my-5"> {props.children}</h5>
    ),
    h6: (props: any) => (
        <h6 className="text-sm font-bold my-5"> {props.children}</h6>
    ),
    blockquote: ({children}: any) => (
        <blockquote className="p-4 my-4 bg-gray-50 border-l-4 border-gray-300 dark:border-gray-500 dark:bg-gray-300">
            <p className="text-xl italic font-medium leading-relaxed text-gray-900 dark:text-white">{children}</p>
        </blockquote>
    ),
    li: ({children}: any) => (
        <li className="ml-4 list-disc"> {children}</li>
    ),
    link: ({href, children}: any) => (
        <a href={href} className="text-blue-500 hover:underline">
            {children}
        </a>
    ),
}

function Posts({post}: Props) {
    console.log(post);
    return (
        <main>
            <Header/>
            <img src={urlFor(post.mainImage).url()!} alt="" className="w-full h-40 object-cover"/>

            <article className="max-w-3xl mx-auto p-5">
                <h1 className="text-3xl mt-10 mb-3">{post.title}</h1>
                <h2 className="text-xl font-light text-gray-500 mb-2">{post.description}</h2>

                <div className="flex items-center space-x-2">
                    <img className="h-10 w-10 rounded-full" src={urlFor(post.author.image).url()!} alt=""/>
                    <p className="font-extralight text-sm">
                        <span className="text-green-600">Blog post by {post.author.name} </span> - Published at {" "}
                        {new Date(post._createdAt).toLocaleString()}
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div className="mt-10">
                    <PortableText dataset={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_DATASET!}
                                  projectId={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID!}
                                  content={post.body}
                                  serializers={serializers}
                    />
                </div>
            </article>

        </main>
    );
}

export default Posts;

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
    const query = `*[_type == "post"]{
        _id,
        slug {
          current
        }
    }`;

    const posts = await sanityClient.fetch(query);

    const paths = posts.map((post: Post) => ({
        params: {
            slug: post.slug.current,
        },
    }));

    return {
        paths,
        fallback: 'blocking',
    };
};

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({params}) => {
    const query = `*[_type == "post" && slug.current == $slug][0]{
        _id,
        _createdAt,
        title,
        author-> {
            name,
            image
        },
        'comments' : *[_type == "comment" &&
          post._ref == ^._id &&
          approved== true],
        description,
        mainImage,
        slug,
        body
    }`;
    const post = await sanityClient.fetch(query, {
        slug: params?.slug,
    });

    if (!post) {
        return {
            notFound: true,
        };
    }

    return {
        props: {
            post,
        },
        revalidate: 60
    };
};
```

The problem is that block overwrites the default serializer. Because of this, it only renders my YouTube video, but no longer renders my headlines, block quotes, etc.
[screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxI8Y.png).

How to properly display video, headlines and block quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [@portabletext/react](https://github.com/portabletext/react-portabletext) instead of [react-portable-text](https://github.com/coreyward/react-portable-text). For customizing individual block styles, I was helped by [this example](https://github.com/portabletext/react-portabletext/blob/main/MIGRATING.md#easier-customization-of-individual-block-styles) from [migration notes](https://github.com/portabletext/react-portabletext/blob/main/MIGRATING.md).

Comment: Do you have a valid example for youtube? because for block type if i use ``youtube: ({value}) => {`` i have no clue why is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The benefit of using react-portable-text is that you don't have to do this:

```js
block: ({node}: any) => {
        if (node._type === 'youtube') {
            console.log(`NODE: ${JSON.stringify(node)}`)
            const {url} = node
            const id = getYouTubeID(url)
            return (<YouTube videoId={id}/>)
        }
    },
```

Instead you can just do this:

```js
youtube: ({ url }) => <YouTube videoId={getYouTubeID(url)} />
```